# way to show plantuml diagram on markdown viewer of visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, markdown, graphviz, plantuml

I know way to write plantuml on markdown using vs code.
But plantuml diagram doesn't appear on markdown viewer...
On the other hand, Plantuml viewer is working very much and markdown viewer also...
markdown viewer only shows graphic icon where I would like to see plantuml diagram...
I think the reason is reference of java home for graphviz...maybe....
If you completed the issue, let me know

for example

````
    ## uml: sequence diagram
Here I will embed PlantUML markup to generate a sequence diagram.

I can include as many plantuml segments as I want in my Markdown, and the diagrams can be of any type supported by PlantUML.

```plantuml
@startuml
    skinparam backgroundColor #EEEBDC
    skinparam handwritten true
    actor Customer
    Customer -> "login()" : username & password
    "login()" -> Customer : session token
    activate "login()"
    Customer -> "placeOrder()" : session token, order info
    "placeOrder()" -> Customer : ok
    Customer -> "logout()"
    "logout()" -> Customer : ok
    deactivate "login()"
@enduml
```
````

Comment: OMG, I could watch Plantuml diagram in Markdown after reboot my pc

Comment: You should post the answer to your own question if you found out :)